# Gridview delete button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

gridview have a problem

```
    protected void DeleteRowButton_Click(Object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionAkaryakit"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();

        int i = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);

        string str1 = "DELETE FROM dbo.Urun_Satis where Musteri_Bilgisi=" + i + "";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

The directory was out of range. It should not be a negative value and should be smaller than the size of the collection. \ R \ nParameter name: index "}

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: The directory was out of range. It should not be a negative value and should be smaller than the size of the collection. \ R \ nParameter name: index "}

for  int i = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line:

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
```

What you need to check ?

- Does your  Grid View has **DataKeys** defined ?
  Because you are accessing the data keys collection of the grid view.
- Assuming Datakeys are defined properly, do you really have the correct no of keys defined ?

When I say, correct no of keys, what if `e.RowIndex = 20` ? this means: **GridView1.DataKeys[20].Value** ? Do you have this number of keys defined for Grid View ??